# why use ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames for ToggleButton.IsChecked instead of BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames?

Tags: animation, storyboard, eventtrigger

For animating UIElement.IsEnabled we can use BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Then why we can't use the same for ToggleButton.IsChecked? What is the need of ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames here? Could somebody clarify this.

```
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ToggleButton.IsChecked)" Storyboard.TargetName="checkBox">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 0):

After an analysis I found the answer. The type of IsChecked is nullable of bool (i.e. bool?) whereas the type of IsEnabled is just a bool. So, null value is applicable for IsChecked. That is why ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames is applicable instead of BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames.